# Test Android Application Using MonkeyRunner

Tags: java, testing, monkeyrunner

I have to make an application that tests an android application using MonkeyRunner tool.I have read android developer documentation.but still dont know how to work with monkey runner.please help me.

I have installed the application on emulator via command line.now I have to start monkey runner and need to generate random touches and inputs. And also need screenshots.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Work with MonkeyRunner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958912/work-with-monkeyrunner)

Answer (score 0):

If you ask any specific questions regarding the **MonkeyRunner**, I am sure people would love to help you. But please avoid asking general broad-range questions that can be easily found by doing some research online.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic script can start with:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyDevice, MonkeyRunner, MonkeyView, MonkeyImage

my_device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

print("Touching coordinate(x=300,y=750)")
my_device.touch(300,750, MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(20)
```

save it in c:\myscript.py and run it with:
**monkeyrunner c:\myscript.py**

Answer (score 0):

You need [UI/Application Exerciser Monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) not `MonkeyRunner` to generates pseudo-random streams of user events such as clicks, touches, or gestures, as well as a number of system-level events.
Event types and frequencies can be specified in the command line.